# devops artifact feed doesn't display icon for nuget packages in visual studio

Tags: nuget, devops, feed

I'm playing around with NuGet packages on Azure DevOps. Packages published to my feed in DevOps Artifacts don't display an icon when looking at it with Visual Studio package manager. When I download the package and create a local resource on my machine, the icons display properly in the Visual Studio package manager.
Any idea why the devops feed doesn't display icons and the local one does? It's the same package, just the source is different.

Comment: The developer team was informed back in 2021, but it is a low prio feature. I don't think that this will be coming in the near future. Source: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/nuget-package-icons-still-not-showing-in-azure-art/1349051